# Android - Error when running benchmarks on Amazon Firetablets (using Jetpack Macrobenchmark)

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, amazon-fire-os, macrobenchmark

The benchmark runs correctly, but in the final stage, when it was supossed to generate .json and .trace, it throws an exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to read any metrics during benchmark (metric list: [androidx.benchmark.macro.StartupTimingMetric@d04ea05]).
Check that you're performing the operations to be measured. For example, if
using StartupTimingMetric, are you starting an activity for the specified package
in the measure block?
```

Code:

```
 benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
   packageName = TARGET_PACKAGE,
   metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
   iterations = DEFAULT_ITERATIONS,
   startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
   compilationMode = compilationMode,
   setupBlock = {
     //Not important
   },
 ) {
    startActivityAndWait()
    BrowsePage(this) {
       waitAppear()
    }
    device.waitForIdle()
 }
```

Expecting:
Run benchmarks and create the logs correctly.